# Querying backslash

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to query a table that has strings with backslash (/). For example strings are:
test
test/test
test4
test5
When I use wild char I do not get "test/test" in the result set. I searched web for including backslash in queries, but couldn't find a solution. Does any one have any idea about this issue?

EDIT:
it is a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM aTable;
```

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you tried?

Comment: How are you viewing the results? backslash has no particular significance in SQL Server. Have you tried your query in SSMS (or Enterprise Manager/Query Analyzer)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should escape backslashes. I've needed to do it when I used PHP's echo statement.

You can escape backslashes by typing a backlash before the backslash you want to escape
Like: \\

You might want to also add backticks to the table name
`aTable`, or there;s a chance that it won't work.